# Select date stored as Unix Timestamp and compare with given Unix TimeStamp

Tags: php, mysqli

I am stuck for couple of Days on SQL specific scenario. The scenario is as follows,

I have a table, lets call it `traffic` which has 2 columns -> `date` and `vehicle (well many more but those are the two I need to match).

The date column is stored as Unix Timestamp. Now this would have been easy to just compare the current date (obtain from php from time() function) however the trick here is that some of these dates have time attached to them also.

For example if you run strtotime(13-02-2017 13:00) and strtotime(13-02-2017) you will get 2 different results. Basically I only care to match the date and not the time.

So I need some way to select the `vehicle` and `date` from the database that are equalled to the current Unix Timestamp but with the trick explained above, so I just need to much the date ONLY if possible.

Comment: [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), perhaps. As in `WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert a timestamp to a datetime, and then use the `DATE()` function to get the date part of that.

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = CURDATE()
```

However, this can't use an index, so another way that can make use of an index is to check if it's in a range of timestamps for the current date:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) + 86399
```

(there are 86400 seconds in a day).

Comment: this works fine but when I do WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 2017-03-18 it fails for some reason, reason I am trying this is because sometimes the date is chosen dynamically, ie it might not need to equal to now.

Comment: You need to put `2017-03-18` in quotes. Otherwise it's subtracting numbers, and it's 1996

Comment: Thank you very much it works...you saved me a lot of trouble because I was originally fetching everything and then checking for dates with php which would be extremely slow in the real world with real data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM traffic WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```